# Erro upload imagem PHP. Warning: move_uploaded_file(): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Erro que está apresentando quando executo o código:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(fotos/7d80310d2fa83125d395d77e6f739bb8.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/PHP/Diego/Funcoes_PHP/upload_imagem/upload.php on line 15 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpvi9j6k' to 'fotos/7d80310d2fa83125d395d77e6f739bb8.png' in /var/www/PHP/Diego/Funcoes_PHP/upload_imagem/upload.php on line 15 erro
```

O código que estou utilizado está logo abaixo:

```
<?php
    include ("conexao.php");

    $msg = false; 

    if(isset($_FILES['arquivo'])){
        $extensao = strtolower(substr($_FILES['arquivo']['name'], -4)); 

        $novo_nome = md5(time()).$extensao;
        $diretorio = 'fotos/'; //diretório para o upload

        /move_uploaded_file(filename, destination)
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novo_nome)){
            echo 'Arquivo salvo com sucesso em : <strong>' . $diretorio . '</strong><br />';
                    echo ' < img src = "' . $novo_nome . '" />';
        }else{
            echo 'erro';
        }

        $sql_code = "INSERT INTO arquivo (codigo, arquivo, data) values (null, '$novo_nome', NOW())"; //função now() pega o horário atual


        mysql_query($sql_code,$conexao) or die (mysql_error(""));

    } 
?>
<?php if($msg!= false) echo "<p> $msg </p>";?>
<h1>Upload</h1>
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    Arquivo: <input type="file" required name="arquivo">
    <input type="submit" value="Salvar">
</form>
```

Comment: Erro de sintaxe confirmado: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Diego, por que criar duas perguntas idênticas?

Answer (score 1):

Diego, você está com problema de permissão em pasta.

Para que você consiga mover arquivo para este diretório:  `$diretorio = 'fotos/';` É necessário que o mesmo tenha permissão para isto.

Com isto, vc pode simplesmente fazer chmod(), aonde você consegue modificar a permissão da pasta.
Faça assim antes desta linha (

```
$diretorio = 'fotos/'; //diretório para o upload
```

) no seu código: `chmod ("/fotos/", 0777);` aonde 0777 é a permissão total na pasta.

Ficando assim:

```
chmod ("/fotos/", 0777);
$diretorio = 'fotos/'; //diretório para o upload
```

E o restante do seu código

Comment: E o que deve ser levado em consideração ao dar a permissão 777, que permite tudo? Quais as brechas de segurança disso? Essa é uma operação que deveria ser executada no PHP? Pois toda vez que for feito um upload será definida as permissões; não bastaria apenas uma vez?